# $(N(\alpha), N(\beta)) = 1 \rightarrow (\alpha, \beta) = 1$ and backwards?

Tags: complex-numbers

Let us have $\alpha, \beta$ arbitrary Gaussian integers.

Is it true, that if $(N(\alpha), N(\beta)) = 1 \rightarrow (\alpha, \beta) = 1$? Is it true backwards?

I know when a Gauss-integer is prime, but I just don't know how I should prove this or show a counter-example. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What's $N(\alpha)$?

Comment: If $\alpha = a+bi$, then $N(\alpha) = a^2+b^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true. Namely, since $N(z) = z \overline{z}$, we see that $w$ divides $z$ iff $N(w)$ divides $N(z)$. Since we know that the ring $\mathbb Z[i]$ is principal (standard proof: it is Euclidean), the ideal $(\alpha, \alpha')$ is spanned by their gcd $d \in \mathbb Z[i]$. We now see that, for any $z \in \mathbb Z[i]$,
$$ z \in (\alpha, \alpha') \;\Leftrightarrow\; d \vert z \;\Leftrightarrow\; N(d) \vert N(z) \;\Leftrightarrow\; N(z) \in (N(d)).$$